# laravel artisan error when listing routes

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm a bit new to laravel and have come across something I don't know how to fix, or even where to start looking. Can anyone explain this, please?

When I run `php artisan route:list`

I get:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
syntax error, unexpected ','
```

I've only made a couple of changes to routes.php. Have since commented those out and cleared the cache, but this still shows, regardless.

**Update - Contents of routes.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/
/**
 * Blade adjustments to make it work with Angular.js
 */
Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>'); // for variables and all things Blade
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<%%', '%%>'); // for escaped data

/**
 * Send requests to Angular.js (may need rethinking eventually because this is
 * essentially a whitelist)
 */
Route::get('/{page?}', function($name = 'dash') {
    return View::make('index');
})->where('page', '(dash|todo|help|settings)');

// Commented out to make Angular.js pages work
//Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');
//Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

/**
* Page View Routes
* Author: Anthony Sinclair
* Date: 31/03/2015
*/
/** User GET for new Users created via the UI */
Route::get('user/new', 'UserController@create');
/** User POST for catching Users created via the UI */
Route::post('user/new', 'UserController@store');

/**
* RESTful API routes
* Author: Anthony Sinclair
* Date: 30/03/2015
*/
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before'=>'auth'), function(){
    /** User based API call routing */
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
    /** People based API call routing */
    Route::resource('recipient', 'PeopleController');
    /** Survey based API call routing */
    Route::resource('survey', 'SurveyController');
    /** Survey Response based API call routing */
    Route::resource('response', 'SurveyResponseController');
    Route::resource('response/token/{survey_token}', 'SurveyResponseController@getResponsesForSurvey');
    /** Survey Instigator - The sending of Surveys */
    Route::resource('send/{survey_id}', 'SurveyInstigatorController@sendSurvey');
});

/** Nps based API call routing */
Route::get('/api/v1/nps/{survey_id}', 'NpsController@getNpsScore');
Route::get('/api/v1/nps/{survey_id}/{filter}', 'NpsController@getNpsScoreFilteredByMonths');
Route::get('/api/v1/nps/{survey_id}/{filter}/{modifier}', 'NpsController@getNpsScoreFilteredByModifier');

Route::get('/api/v1/nps/response/{survey_id}/{recipient_id}/{nps_score}', 'SurveyResponseController@requestSurveyResponse');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController'
]);
```

Even checking my routes.php - shows no errors:

```
php -l app\http\routes.php
No syntax errors detected in app\http\routes.php
```

Comment: what is in your route.php?

Comment: @sgt - updated my question with routes.php content

Comment: Where does the error occur? There should be a file and line number mentioned in the exception.

Comment: @lukasgeiter I pasted in the exception above. That's all I get, hence my confusion.

Comment: @LokiSinclair when running the command you can pass the option `-vvv` to get maximum verbosity, which should show you the file and line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to go to `storage/framework` and delete `routes.php`. I suspect that the syntax error might have been cached.

Comment: When running artisan, the app is bootstrapped, and the routes are loaded. If a syntax error is present, it stops the execution, and the command never gets run unfortunately

Comment: Found it! Was an error in one of my Controllers. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, but only when ran on my local computer. If I ran `route:list` on server, it worked fine. The problem was my computer was using PHP v5.6 and the server was using PHP v7.0.

I was using the new `??` operator in a controller, so it was throwing a syntax error cause PHP v5.6 doesn't understand that operator.